Content Security Policy errors when using Font Awesome icons and use-client
I am using the Font Awesome SVG pack via npm within a NextJS application using the App router.
I have added a middleware to generate a nonce value as detailed in the Next docs.
The cspHeader itself looks like this:
const cspHeader = `
      default-src 'self';
      script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic';
      style-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}';
      img-src 'self' blob: data:;
      font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
      object-src 'none';
      base-uri 'self';
      form-action 'self';
      frame-ancestors 'none';
      upgrade-insecure-requests;

I've also configured the autoAddCss to false in my layout.tsx file, as per the Font Awesome docs
import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
config.autoAddCss = false

In terms of functionality, everything seems to be working okay. If I stick to server components, everything is fine.
However, I have noticed that if I use any components with use-client, I get the following CSP error in the console:
168-ded29a44f3549779.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-XYZ'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-XYZ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
Is there a best practice I can be following to avoid this, or is it unavoidable with this setup? For what it's worth, I can't actually see any styling / script errors when the page loads.
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks
